# web analytics in SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-analytics

Is it possible in SharePoint Foundation 2013 to get reports on usage for the site?
I see a lot of info on it for the full version, not much info on foundation. and I don't see half the settings .

Ie as per instructions from Technet

> "On the Site Settings page, in the Site Collection Administration
>   section, click Popularity and Search Reports."

I don't have **Popularity and search reports** option.

Does it exist in foundation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have SharePoint server 2013 because now **Analytics** are a part of Search service in SharePoint 2013.

It is **surely not available** in `SharePoint Foundation 2013`

> There is much confusion around the SharePoint community on whether or
>   not web analytics works in SharePoint Foundation 2013.
>
> After working on numerous SharePoint 2013 environments, I can confirm
>   that SharePoint Foundation is lacking this feature. I came across this
>   [technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5372109c-8a6e-4d31-aa34-13b6cbde52cf/sharepoint-foundation-2013-web-analytics?forum=sharepointgeneral) discussing if the Foundation version of SharePoint
>   2013 has web analytics or not, and the top response is from a
>   SharePoint MVP and stating in short that Foundation does not have
>   analytics.

You can check further details in below mentioned link.

[Where to Find Usage Reports for SharePoint 2013](http://blog.fpweb.net/why-no-analytics-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013/#.Vzma9-Swl8w)

Comment: Is above given information helps you to understand the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In sharePoint 2013 Web Analytics has been completely redesigned and Web Analytics Service Application has been replaced with Analytics engine.

For this you need Search Service Application.

As per Technet, this feature is not available for SharePoint Foundation 2013.Read below Article and look for Analytics Platform.

[SharePoint feature availability across on-premises solutions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/b6db338b-522b-44bf-afb7-1de7827691d0#bkmk_AnalyticsPlatform)